# Why does domain hosted with no-ip.org get rejected by browser's phishing filter/malware detection

Tags: certificate, windows-server-2012-r2, dynamic-ip

I'm trying to host a tiny website on my home server (Windows 2012) and I am using a domain hosted with no-ip.org.

That domain is forwarded to my server here at home, which is only hooked up to a simple DSL router, but people tell me that when browsing the site it is often (if not always) rejected, or simply would not load at all.
Upon reloading and/or turning off the security warnings the site works as expected.

Bottom line is I'd like to authenticate my server somehow to allow the site to load without people having to mess with the browser settings.

**I don't need or want SSL, much less pay for it. I'm just after some soft of "authenticity" that tells the browsers my site isn't "bad". How can I do this?**

Comment: Not to scare you off in any way, but ServerFault is [a question and answer site for professional system and network administrators.](http://serverfault.com/about). This setup doesn't sound very professional. Perhaps the sister site [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) is where you wanted to ask your question?

Answer (score 2):

Trust is not something you can force upon others. If it was up to a site operator to declare whether they could be trusted or not, what would malicious parties do?

If I was on a dynamic-IP setting up a HTTP web site that I wanted to look "real", I would:

- focus on the content, complying with standards, passing HTML validations
- make sure all machines on your network are free from malware
- buy a domain in a "normal" TLD
- update the zone each time my IP would change
- get an SSL certificate from [StartCom](http://www.startssl.com/).

And then consider moving to a cheap VPS, of course...

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is something simple.

Do not host the site there.

Use Cloudflare to give the site a cloudflare IP, and cloudflare pulls the site from you.